# Can we change the name of values of a categorical variable in the tbl_summary function of the gtsummary package in R?

Tags: r, gtsummary

Continuing from the title, can I change the values of education from '1,2,3,4' to 'primary school, high school, university etc.' ?

We can change in the output, but I wished to know if it's possible in the code. I have tried reading the documentation of gtsummary but did not find the answer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PLgI.png)

Comment: Nothing to do with `grsummary`. Just change your data: `df <- df %>% mutate(education = factor(edu, levels = c(1:4), labels = c("primary school", "high school", "university", "etc.")))`

Comment: Could you provide an example dataset?

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang has answered the question; his suggestion makes sense

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggests, it's about the levels of a factor variable.

```
data(mtcars)

as_tibble(mtcars)

mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
levels(mtcars$cyl) <- c("low", "middle", "high")

library(gtsummary)
tbl_summary(mtcars)
```

[image]